# I want to check another field When I get dublicate key error for email (unique) in mongodb findoneandupdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: userFindByid }, {
    $set: {
      "email": req.body.email,
      "username": req.body.username,
      "phone_number": req.body.phone_number,
      "address": req.body.address,
      "isBenefactor": req.body.isBenefactor,
      "location": req.body.location
    }
  }, { runValidators: true, context: 'query' }, (err, doc) => {

    if (err) {
// if request email has already exist in db I want to check that emails isDeleted field in here . if isDeleted is true I want to update .
      return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
    else {
      return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Your account was updated' });
    }
  })
//


Let me explain  scenario clearly,
 I registered with an email address(first@gmail.com) then I deleted my account =>(first@gmail.com)=>isDeleted=true 
After that I again registered with another email address(second@gmail.com)=>isDeleted=false
Now I want to update my second email address with first one I will get an unique key error because (first@gmail.com) is in mydb ,but I have to da update process because  (first@gmail.com)=>IsDelete=true 
If I use { 'email': req.body.email, 'isDeleted': true} I can not update (second@gmail.com)=>isDeleted=false
```

I can fix the problem by using too much if statements , but I dont want to use if statements too much. I am looking for best practice for that problem.

I hope I could explain
Here is my code block , can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS ANSWER ASSUMES YOU ARE USING MONGOOSE!

One way you can do is instead of using `findOneAndUpdate` you can use `.save` this way you can issue a hook on mongoose.

For example, you would do `User.save(...)` then you go to your schema code and you add the following (assuming your schema name is `UserSchema`)

```
UserSchema.post('save', function(error, doc, next) {
  // Error code 11000 means this is a duplicate
  if (error.name === 'MongoError' && error.code === 11000) {
    // So instead of throwing an error you would do anything you want
    // Such as look for the other record and delete it, update its isDelete 
    // field, remove email, etc... really is up to you

  } 
  next()
});
```

**EDIT:** Of course before `User.save(...)` you need to find the user!
For example,

```
User.findOne({_id:1}, function(err, doc){
  // Update doc values
  // Finally do doc.save(...)
})
```

You can make it look much better by using the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) library and using `async.waterfall`

---

**EDIT2:** Okay so now that I understand your requirement better, here is your best solution in my opinion.

1. Find the user you want to update
2. Change email
3. Save

On the other side, you need to have a hook (unfortunately its poorly documented, you have to do your own digging but here is a link to mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html))
Here is how this will work
1. Hook a pre save (before actually saving execute specific block of code)
2. The block of code will only execute when the email is modified (we dont want to execute it everytime, its just a waste of resources)
3. The block of code will use `deleteOne` and delete the user matching that email

**NOTE:** For best performance make sure to index the email and make it unique!

I have created the full (similar to what you want) project with the code on [here](https://repl.it/@Muhand1/mongoose-hook)

But if you wish here are also some snippet

```
// This will run before saving the object
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  let user = this 

  // Make sure to run only when email is modified
  if(user.isModified('email')) {
    // IF the email was modified, then attempt to delete a record with this email (if there is one, then it will be deleted otherwise it will just continue)
    this.constructor.deleteOne({email:this.email, isDeleted:true}, (err) => {
      err ? next(err) : next()
    })
  } else {
    next()
  }
})


  // Code to save/update the user
  User.findOne({_id:"1"}, function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  } else {
    if (user) {
      user.email = "test2@test.com"
      user.save(err => {
        err ? console.log(err) : console.log("Success!")
      })
    } else {
      console.log("User was not found!")
    }
  }
})
```

Good luck!